# Unable to redirect using angular routeprovider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, route-provider

i am new to angular i when i am not able to redirect to the signup.html page when i hit the locahost:port/projectname/

eventhough i specified the template url for singup in app.js i am getting 404

but when i hit the locahost:port/projectname/signup.html the file was opening am i doing anything wrong?

i want to get the signup.html when i hit locahost:port/projectname/

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('pollApp', ['ngRoute']);
  app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
     .when('/Welcome', {
         templateUrl: '/Welcome.html',
         controller: 'submitCtrl'
       })
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/signup.html',
        controller: 'submitCtrl'
       })
       .otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/Welcome.html'
       });
}]);
```

submitController.js

```
app.controller('submitCtrl',['$scope', '$http', '$location',

  function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.timeZones =      [
     { label: '(GMT-09:00) Alaska', value: 'Alaska' },
     { label: '(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)', value: 'Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)' }
    ];  


    $scope.submit=function()    {
        var userDetails=new Object();
        userDetails.firstname=$scope.firstname;
        userDetails.lastname=$scope.lastname;
        userDetails.Companyname=$scope.Companyname;
        userDetails.Email=$scope.Email;
        userDetails.timezone=$scope.timezone;
        console.log(userDetails);
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          data: userDetails,
          url:'/mongopractise/rest/signup/userdata',
          headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            console.log("success data"+JSON.stringify(data));
            $scope.username=data;
            $location.url('/Welcome.html').replace();;

          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              console.log("Failure data"+data);
          });
}

 }]);
```

Signup.html

```
              <html lang="en" ng-app="pollApp">
               <head>
               <meta charset="utf-8">
              <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
             <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <title>Welcome!</title>

                <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
                <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                 <div class="container" ng-controller='submitCtrl'>

       <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                                  <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">First name:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input class="form-control" value="Jane" type="text" ng-      model="firstname">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Last name:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input class="form-control" value="Bishop" type="text" ng-model="lastname">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Company:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input class="form-control" value="" type="text" ng-model="Companyname">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input class="form-control" value="janesemail@gmail.com" type="text" ng-model="Email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Time Zone:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="ui-select">
                        <select id="user_time_zone" class="form-control" ng-model="timezone" ng-options="timeZones as timeZones.label for timeZones in timeZones">

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" ng-click='submit()' value="Save Changes" type="button"> <span class=""></span>

                    <input class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" type="reset">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        </head>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your routes don't include '/projectname', which I assume is your application context. You need to include that in the route urls for it to work properly.

Comment: Even after adding the /projectname i am not able to redirect still it was saying 404

Comment: The 404 will be coming from your server, is it requesting the correct url, if not what url is it requesting. Also your template urls should also have the /projectname appended to them. In these cases I normally define a global variable contextPath and the append that to all urls in the route definition.

Comment: server was not requesting any url ? whatever the url i have specified like http://locahost:808/projectname/signup it was giving the page not found i am using tomcat server and this project was based on maven java + Angular

Comment: What happens if you directly request http://localhost:8080/projectname/singup.html

Comment: it was opening singup.html page

Comment: can you attach the main html page you are using which has the ng-view in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71864/discussion-between-devi-kiran-and-thedoctor).

Answer (score 0):

Any path after your port is expected to be in `routeProvider` config. your sever should **serve** the  projectname folder then

```
.when('/', {templateUrl: '/signup.html',  
controller: 'submitCtrl'
 })
```

will work as expected