# Angular app always redirects to default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, gulp, route-provider

I am building a new Rails API / Angular app. I have two basic pages, one which is the default generated by Gulp. I'm a bit lost on these redirects.

If I type this:

http://localhost:9000/main

The browser redirects the main page at this address (note the hash):

http://localhost:9000/#/main

When I type:

http://localhost:9000/sentences

then the browser redirects the main page also, with this address in the browser:

http://localhost:9000/sentences#/main

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myapp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/sentences', {
         templateUrl: 'app/sentences/sentences.html',
         controller: 'SentencesCtrl'
      })
     .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/main'
      });  
  })
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the $locationProvider and setting html5Mode to true works, not really sure why.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myapp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
      .when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/sentences', {
         templateUrl: 'app/sentences/sentences.html',
         controller: 'SentencesCtrl'
      })
     .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/main'
      });  
  }) 
;
```

I also needed to add a base tag to my index.html

```
    <base href="/">
```

Comment: Any clear explanation on why this is required would become the accepted answer.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744335/unable-to-redirect-using-angular-routeprovider?rq=1 and interesting post: http://www.jonahdempcy.com/2014/12/29/angularjs-error-locationnobase-location-html5-mode-requires-base-tag-present/